# ifstream var.fail() in function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project for a class where we must have nothing in our main except for variable declarations and function calls.

Usually I check for a in/outfile failure by these lines of code in the main:

```
if( (inFile.fail()) || (outfile.fail())
{
    cout << "File I/O Failure";
    return 1;
}
```

For this project however all my code needs to embedded in functions.  I have a      function `void openFile(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)` which sets the `infile` and `outfie` names and opens them.

The question is how do I write a function that would test for failure and terminate the program on fail, but not close the program.

For instance:

```
int file_failure(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)
{
     if( (fin.fail()) || (fout.fail()) ) 
     {
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       // don't return a value.
     }
}
```

My hangup or maybe my misunderstanding is `int main()` closes upon receiving an int value, which is what I want IF there is a failure in opening the in/out file, but I do not want my file_failure() to return an int to main and close the program if the i/o is good.

Again I absolutely cannot have any code aside from var declaration and function calls in the main for this project.

-Thanks
Josh

Comment: Define "terminate ..., but not close the program".

Comment: The program closes *when main returns*. Not when something else returns to main.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that your statement `terminate the program on fail, but not close the program.` is contradictory with itself.

So far if I understand what you are trying to say I would use exception safety for this.

```
int file_failure(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout){
     if( (fin.fail()) || (fout.fail()) ) throw std::runtime_error("File I/O Failure");
     else
     {
       // don't return a value.
     }
     return val; // what ever you want to return
}

int main(){
    try {
        file_failure(fin, fout);
    }catch(std::exception& e){ 
         // control reach here if file_failure throw exception
         std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
         exit(1); // the parameter to exit function gives the Exit Status
                  // this exit function terminates your program
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) more for Exit Status.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, I'm in a intro to programming and we haven't gotten into exceptions yet so try, throw, and catch are foreign to me.  I'll look into it for my  own benefit but the exception handling can't be in main, main needs to be completely empty except for function calls and var declaration. I didn't read the statement carefully enough, what I meant to say was "if the I/O fails terminate the program, else continue).

Comment: @JoshuaGahan  in that case why don't you just do `if( (fin.fail()) || (fout.fail()) ) exit(1);` you could avoid the exception safety thingy

Comment: Yeah I'll do that then, thank you I didn't know about exit() we've only ever terminated a program by returning 0 or returning 1 if there was some error.